# VS Code shows "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError" while start debugging

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pip, vscode-debugger

I executed the "Start Debugging" on Visual Studio Code to debug a Django website.

However, the VS Code shows "**Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'maintenance_mode'**".

[image]

I've used "**pip3 install django-maintenance-mode**" to installed the "**django-maintenance-mode**" v0.14.0.

My INSTALLED_APPS in the WebServer/settings.py includes the '**maintenance_mode**' as the https://pypi.org/project/django-maintenance-mode/ mentioned.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'maintenance_mode',
       ...
       ...
]
```

If I remove the usage of the 'maintenance_mode' from INSTALLED_APPS, then the debugging mode works.

But I need to use the 'maintenance_mode' module.

What should I do to make debugging work with 'maintenance_mode' module?

Comment: did you install package in same environment your VS Code is running it from

Comment: Hi, somehow after installing the package in the virtualenv environment, the debugging works! Thank you!!